# UItableViewCell Expand/Collapse Animation (Works when expanding, but not collapsing)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uianimation

just as a background, this question is related to this one I posted earlier: [Trying to expand/collapse UITableViewCell from a UIButton on the custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428238/trying-to-expand-collapse-uitableviewcell-from-a-uibutton-on-the-custom-cell)

To summarize, I have a UITableView with several custom table cells.  Each custom UITableViewCell has a text area, followed by a "View More" button.  Essentially, each cell will initially display 3 lines of text, but when the user taps the "View More" button, the cell should expand to the entire text area height.  Tapping the button again will collapse the cell.

I think this is difficult to visualize, so I have taken a short video here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762437/cell-animation.mov

(it's about a 3.5mb file, so shouldnt take that long to load).  In the video, I show a cell doing the expand/collapse animation.  When doing the expanding, the "View More" button animates downward.  When tapping it again, it just jumps back up to its original position with no animation.  **Edit: Sorry, I should be more clear.  The UITableView is animating the cells correctly, what I am asking is how to make the "View More" button animate correctly.**

I've got the expand/collapse working (whether I did it right or wrong is another matter!), but the animations arent working as I expect.  The expanding animation works, but not the collapsing.

In each custom UITableViewCell class, I have a IBAction that is called when the user taps the "View More" button.  I also keep track of the cells that are currently expanded in a NSMutableArray.  When the user taps the "Close" button, that cell is removed from the array.

In my tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath, I check the array to see which cells should be expanded and which should show at their default size.

I am doing so with this code:

```
// Check if the array contains the particular cell, if so, then it needs to be expanded 
if([expandedRows containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            // Expand the cell's text area to fit the entire contents
            [cell.textLabel sizeToFitFixedWidth:cell.textLabel.frame.size.width];

            // Find the new Y-position of where the "Close" button.
            // The new Y position should be at the bottom of the newly expanded text label

            CGFloat bottomYPos = cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y + cell.textLabel.frame.size.height;

            // Get a rect with the "Close" button's frame and new Y position
            CGRect buttonRect = cell.showAllButton.frame;
            buttonRect.origin.y = bottomYPos;

            // Animation block to shift the "Close" button down to its new rect             
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                             animations:^{
                                 cell.showAllButton.frame = buttonRect;
                                 [cell.showAllButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 NSLog(@"Done 1!");
                             }];
        }
        else
        {
            // This cell is currently collapsed

            // Get the button rect and subtract the height delta to put it back
            // OriginalCellSizes is where I keep track of the original Y positions
            CGRect buttonRect = cell.showAllButton.frame;
            buttonRect.origin.y -= cell.frame.size.height - [[originalCellSizes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];

            // Animation block for the Button    
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 cell.showAllButton.frame = buttonRect;
                                 [cell.showAllButton setTitle:@"View More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 NSLog(@"Done! 2");
                             }];
        }
```

Upon investigating, I found that in the "else" branch of that if-else, the buttonRect is already at the same Y position as the original position.   I suspect that this is why there is no animation happening, bu I'm not sure.

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

simple way to do this......

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

insertIndexPaths is an array of NSIndexPaths to be inserted to your table.

deleteIndexPaths is a array of NSIndexPaths to be deleted from your table.

Example array format for index paths :

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
        nil];
```

got it from this question...[this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560602/add-delete-uitableviewcell-with-animation)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: Yes, and that is even more baffling.